# /usr/bin/which returns cryptic error "which: no ls in ((null))"

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a simple shell program. When I use /usr/bin/which with my shell in mac osx and ubuntu, it acts normally. When I use the exact same command on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 6.3 (Santiago), I get this error: "which: no ANYCOMMANDHERE in ((null))".

Is there any intuition for this? I can't even find what the error means (Let me know if showing my source will help).

**EDIT: My path is (from inside the shell):**

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Thanks, 
Jon

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?  It sounds like you have no `PATH` environment variable defined.

Comment: It sounds like a `$PATH` problem.

Comment: echo $PATH

/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: Why are you using `which` in a shell script anyhow? It's bad practice to do so; if you really to know where things are, use the shell builtin `type`, but if you just want to start them, just call your commands without qualifying and let the shell find them. There's no reason to call `$FOO` when you can just call `foo`.

Comment: Charles Duffy. I'm writing a shell. Not a bash program.

Comment: Does your shell correctly pass some environment settings to its children?  Maybe try having it execute `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: How are you executing `/usr/bin/which` from within your shell?

Answer (score 5):

The string `(null)` is substituted by some C libraries for arguments to printf's `%s` (string) conversion specifier, when the corresponding argument is a NULL pointer, e.g. for

```
 char *path = 0; /* This would normally be = getenv("PATH"). */
 printf ("which: no foobar in (%s)\n", path);
```

It appears that either your PATH environment variable is unset, or not exported. In these cases `getenv("PATH")` returns 0. As a last possibility, your `which` utility might have a mighty bug).

Does it work properly if you say `export PATH`?

Comment: Do you think it matters if I'm using /bin/tcsh (just realized that is the default on the server)?  (Export isn't built in to tcsh I think (or my shell))

Comment: A csh variant? Ugh :-) Then you should say `setenv PATH=...your path here...`

Comment: But wouldn't it not matter since which is getting called from my shell? And if it does, how can I make this portable? Also, I dropped into /bin/sh, and ran my shell from there, and it didn't work.

Comment: It matters because you want to make sure your PATH is exported to the environment. The Bourne Shells do this with `export`, the csh lineage with `setenv`. We want to make sure PATH is set, so we can find if there's a problem in the `which` utility or somewhere else.

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin. My bad.. I posted this in an edit.

Comment: Okay, we know PATH is set. But is it also exported to the environment and your shell application? What does just `setenv` say? Does it have a line for PATH? Does your shell application pass the environment to the utilities it forks? I.e. which exec family function do you use?

Comment: Yes, that. @Jonathan The `PATH` shell variable is set, but it's clearly not present in the environment (which is pretty unusual but technically possible).

Comment: @Jends: No, the csh/tcsh syntax is `setenv PATH ...`, with no `=`. Or you can use `set path = ( dir1 dir2 dir3 ... )`; the shell array variable `$path` and the environment variable `$PATH` are automatically tied together.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what all other people here already answered - PATH not being set, is true in one way, but false in another way.

I had the same problem (using bash). It seems, a bash "feature" turns into a miss-feature: Bash creates a shell variable (not environment variable!) PATH which it then uses for lookups.

So, the situation is: There exists a shell variable called PATH. But it's not an environment variable. This means, it's not exported to newly created child processes. One thing, we should learn from this, is that using
    echo $PATH
is no way to figure out whether the *environment* variable PATH is set. Same prolem with
    set | grep "^PATH="
However, one way to do so is by using the *external* command env:
    env | grep "^PATH="

Example shell session:

```
$ env -i bash
# A new shell is started with empty environment.
# What follows happens in this new shell:
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ set | grep "^PATH="
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ env | grep "^PATH="
$ which ls
which: no ls in ((null))
$ export PATH
$ env | grep "^PATH="
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can ask the shell to act like a login shell, for bash it's -l. With that, /etc/profile and other files are sources which set up PATH properly by default:

```
$ env -i bash -l
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

The alternative, is to export PATH, see above.

Comment: Ran into this issue installing txt2man, and this resolved it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same output from tcsh:

```
env -u PATH which ls
which: no ls in ((null))
```

In csh and tcsh, there's a distinction between environment variables (which are common to all processes) and shell variables (which are local to the current invocation of the shell). It uses the same syntax to refer to both, e.g., `$PATH`. If you have a shell variable and an environment variable of the same name, then `$PATH` refers to the shell variable.

[t]csh uses different syntax to *set* shell vs. environment variables:

```
set shell_var = foo
setenv env_var bar
```

(Bourne-based shells such as bash have a different syntax and a different terminology; an environment variable is a shell variable that's been "exported", or that's inherited from the calling process.)

Based on the symptoms you describe, you have a shell variable `$PATH` (which is useless), but no environment variable of the same name. That shouldn't normally happen.  Check your `.cshrc`, `.tcshrc`, and/or `.login` files for statements that set `$PATH`.

You should be able to work around the immediate problem like this:

```
setenv PATH "$PATH"   # set the environment variable
unset PATH            # unset the shell variable, just to avoid confusion
```

(Don't do the `unset PATH` until you've confirmed that things are working correctly.)

Just to add to the frivolity, [t]csh has a special *shell* variable `$path` (note lowercase); its value is an array consisting of the `:`-separated components of the `$PATH` environment variable. Setting either will automatically update the other:

```
 setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin # sets $path to ( /usr/bin /bin )
 set path = ( /usr/local/bin $path ) # sets $PATH to '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
```

This can be convenient, but if you prefer you can just ignore `$path` and deal with `$PATH`. Just make sure that you're setting the environment variable `$PATH` (using `setenv`), not the useless shell variable of the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think it might have to do with default env var passing to children with fork. I'm not 100% though.. still testing.

Comment: Children created by `fork()` inherit the `$PATH` environment variable of their parents. Every process should have a default `$PATH`. If `$PATH` is unset for a given process, something must have unset it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `PATH` environment variable is the problem. For instance, if you run `which asdf` normally you will get something like:

```
which: no asdf in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...)
```

So it appears your PATH environment variable is something like `(NULL)`. The other possibility is that there's something wrong with the which binary on your RHEL box.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue is specific to redhat and the forking mechanism. Child processes are not given the default env vars while in ubuntu and mac osx they are. This means that I had to explicitly set the envp to the parent's (in a call to execve).

Apologies for the misleading phrasing in my question (although it is hard to pinpoint these type of things).

Thanks for all the help!
Jon

Comment: Er. This makes no sense. How were you calling fork/exec before?

Comment: I wasn't explicitly passing the environment variables to the child. There apparently is a difference between the different linux flavors for this behavior.

Comment: My point was, what _exactly_ did your call to exec look like? You can't just _leave them out_ if you call execve/execle, and if that worked it only did so by accident - you have to call execv/execl to get it to implicitly pass the parent's environment. I'm asking this because _there's not actually a difference, or any sane reason for there to be a difference_, if you did it right. It's also possible that _none_ of them were getting the parent's environment, and the implementation of `/usr/bin/which` (which is not a standard tool) was doing something different.